# Android DJI SDK error when video displayed for a few seconds

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I have no idea why I am getting this error:

```
E/UsbAccessoryService: recvBufferThread.start
E/UsbAccessoryService: RecvOsdRunnable true
E/UsbAccessoryService: rate 0.52 KB
E/UsbAccessoryService: parseVideoThread.start
E/DJIPackManager: pack senderType=14 cmdSet=9
E/UsbAccessoryService: ParseVideoRunnable true
E/DJIBaseProduct: Camera needCreateNew: true
E/DJIBaseProduct: put component
E/DJIBaseProduct: Gimbal needCreateNew: true
E/DJIBaseProduct: put component
E/DJIBaseProduct: FlightController needCreateNew: true
E/DJIBaseProduct: put component
E/DJIBaseProduct: update battery platformType: P4
E/DJIBaseProduct: update battery phantom
E/DJIBaseProduct: Battery needCreateNew: true
E/Event: Could not dispatch event: class dji.midware.data.model.P3.DataEyeGetPushFrontAvoidance to subscribing class class dji.sdk.FlightController.DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant$InnerEventBus
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at dji.sdk.FlightController.DJIIntelligentFlightAssistant$InnerEventBus.onEventBackgroundThread(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                  at dji.thirdparty.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:569)
                                                                  at dji.thirdparty.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:513)
                                                                  at dji.thirdparty.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:475)
                                                                  at dji.thirdparty.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:365)
                                                                  at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.t.post(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.t.setPushRecData(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.t.setPushRecPack(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.l.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.l.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.l.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.usb.P3.UsbAccessoryService$1.onGetBody(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.f.a.f.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.f.a.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at dji.midware.usb.P3.UsbAccessoryService$RecvBufferRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The video feed from the TextureView appears for a couple seconds then the activity involving displaying the video feed exits to the MainActivity. (I use a MainActivity to transition to the VideoFeedActivity through a menu). I can't figure out what the null pointer is or where its coming from because I believe I am initializing everything properly but it appears that is not the case. In the SurfaceTextureListener for the implemented function onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) I am performing an analysis of the bitmap for each frame. However I doubt that is the issue, I believe it has something to do with the initialization of the drone's objects and how they are interacting. I tried to turn off the IntelligentFlightAssistant before loading the video stream; however, this had no affect.

Comment: Please write your solution in an answer and accept it two days later. You are not supposed to edit your question to add the "SOLUTION FOUND" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was:

I was creating a new thread every time a new frame was made to analyze the image and this was causing the failure. To fix this I made it so a new thread can only be made if a current thread isn't in use. (I know this kind of defeats the purpose of the threads but I don't want this action slowing down the processes running the app). Anyways this solved the problem and now the program works fine.